# Need to print a two to five digit number following an equal sign in file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to determine the best way to search a file with python for a 2 to 5 digit string  and print the value if it is found immediately after this string: "BusID ="

I do not want to print the whole line as I am searching a JSON file which is one giant line.

My sample file looks like:

```
BusID = 98765
BusID = 987
BusID = 98/
foo BusID = 9876/ 
123
1234
2345 foo 
# 8912 foo foo foo foo
#7654
-8999
\6478
/9023
$7654
A3356
12345
```

How can I print the numeric values of any length following "BusID =" ?

Thus far I am able to print the line containing a four digit value after an equal sign.

```
import re
myfile = open("C:\\Users\\frank\\sample_file.txt")
# read in the file as a list of lines
lines = myfile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if "BusID" in line and re.search(r'\d\d\d\d', line) is not None:
        # print the line
        print(line)
```

which outputs

```
BusID = 98765
BusID = 987
BusID = 98/
foo BusID = 9876/
```

How do I print just the numeric values?  I am struggling here and appreciate any input.

Comment: Your sample file doesn't look like JSON.

Comment: My real file is json. The sample is not. JSON is tot unreadable. Sorry I didn't get that point across clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
with open("C:\\Users\\frank\\sample_file.txt", "r") as myfile:
    print(re.findall(r'BusID\s*=\s*(\d+)', myfile.read()))
```

**Regex**: `BusID\s*=\s*(\d+)`

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BusID                    'BusID'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: Did you write te explanation manually, or is there a method to generate such?

Comment: @SayandipDutta There are ways to do this automatically.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you could point me in the right direction. A link may be? Thank you.

Comment: @SayandipDutta https://myregextester.com/index.php for example. In R, there is a library that does the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the number after the equals sign, the following code will print the number.
`print(line.split(' = ')[1])`

This would be replacing the line:
`print(line)`